# how to easily sum two hashMap<String,Integer>?

Tags: java, hashmap, hashtable

I have two `HashMap<String,Integer>`

How can I sum them easily?

Meaning that for String "a" the key will be sum of (value from Map1 + value from Map2)?

I can iterate every item of Map2 and add manually to Map1.

But thought there might be an easier way?

I prefer summing the Integers into one of the maps. Not creating a new one

Comment: Do you want to create new map which will be combination of previous two, or do you want to update first map by adding to it second map?

Comment: I feel like an example of the expected result structure would be useful

Comment: Show us some code. Intuitively, I would say: get both `keySet`s, join them in one `Set`, look up each value in each map, sum them up and add them to a new map.

Comment: @Pshemo I prefer summing the Integers into one of the maps. Not creating a new one

Comment: Do you have to construct a new `HashMap` per se? You can create an object that has references to both `HashMap`s and acts as a hashmap by query both. A bit like a view on a collection.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> I prefer summing the Integers into one of the maps. Not creating a new one

In that case you can use [`merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method added to `Map` interface in Java 8. Otherwise take a look at other answers like https://stackoverflow.com/a/33640413

Anyway `Map#merge(key, value, merginFunction)` method is similar to `Map#add(key, value)`. Only difference is fact that it requires *third argument* which is:

- function used to decide what value to put in map *if it already contains specified key*. Decision will be made based on old and new value (so its lambda may look like `(v1, v2) -> v1 + v2` for summing values, or we could use `Integer::sum` method reference).

So you could simply use:

```
map2.forEach((k, v) -> map1.merge(k, v, Integer::sum));
```

Now your `map1` will copy all key-values from `map2` and in case it already has such key, value will be calculated by adding old and new value. Result will be stored in map under that common key.

DEMO:

```
Map<String, Integer> m1 = new HashMap<>();
m1.put("a", 1);
m1.put("b", 2);
Map<String, Integer> m2 = new HashMap<>();
m2.put("a", 3);
m2.put("c", 10);

System.out.println(m1);
System.out.println(m2);

//iterate over second map and merge its elements into map 1 using 
//same key and sum of values
m2.forEach((k, v) -> m1.merge(k, v, Integer::sum));

System.out.println("===========");
System.out.println(m1);
```

Output:

```
{a=1, b=2}
{a=3, c=10}
===========
{a=4, b=2, c=10}
```

Answer (score 7):

in case you like Java 8:

```
Map<String, Integer> sum(Map<String, Integer>... maps) {
    return Stream.of(maps)    // Stream<Map<..>>
            .map(Map::entrySet)  // Stream<Set<Map.Entry<..>>
            .flatMap(Collection::stream) // Stream<Map.Entry<..>>
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                      Map.Entry::getValue,
                                      Integer::sum));
}
```

can sum up arbitrary amounts of maps. It turns the array of maps into a `Stream<Map.Entry<String, Integer>` in the first few lines, then collects all the entries into a new `Map` while supplying a "merge function" in case of duplicate values.

alternatively something along the lines of

```
void addToA(HashMap<String, Integer> a, HashMap<String, Integer> b) {
    for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : b.entrySet()) {
        Integer old = a.get(entry.getKey());
        Integer val = entry.getValue();
        a.put(entry.getKey(), old != null ? old + val : val);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no easy way. You need to iterate them manually.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class HashMapSum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        map1.put("a", 1);
        map1.put("b", 2);
        map1.put("c", 3);

        Map<String, Integer> map2 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        map2.put("a", 4);
        map2.put("b", 5);
        map2.put("d", 6);

        Set<String> keySet = new HashSet<String>();
        keySet.addAll(map1.keySet());
        keySet.addAll(map2.keySet());

        Map<String, Integer> map3 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        Integer val1, val2;
        for (String key : keySet) {
            val1 = map1.get(key);
            val1 = (val1 == null ? 0 : val1);
            val2 = map2.get(key);
            val2 = (val2 == null ? 0 : val2);
            map3.put(key, val1 + val2);
        }

        System.out.println(map3.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It helped me.