# Calculate Percentage by comparing 2 Maps using java 8 stream API?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have two maps of String with long , I want to calculate percentage by comparing one map value with another map value.

For eg :

```
Map<String, Long> map1 = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Long>();
map1.put("test1", (long) 20);
map1.put("test2", (long) 30);
Map<String, Long> map2 = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Long>();
map2.put("test1", (long) 120);
map2.put("test2", (long) 120);
```

I want to calculate average of test1 and test2 value by comparing map2 value with map1 value.

Desired Result should be

```
resultmap = [test1 : "16.66%", test2 : "25%"]
```

Comment: Can you show us how you calculate those values?  Is test1 = 20/120 = 0.1667?

Comment: yes test1=20/120 * 100 = 16.67%  test2=30/120 * 100 = 25%

Comment: I don't know about "flawed" but I'm having a hard time thinking how to do this with streams.  Procedurally it's not too hard.

Comment: @Aominè I want to achieve using java 8 stream API. If you have any easier way, Please suggest.

Comment: You'd probably want to look into using pairs to clean up the data structure. https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html

Comment: @markspace I got a similar solution using 2 maps with sum [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33640088/how-to-easily-sum-two-hashmapstring-integer). But I want to calculate average instead.

Comment: Stop calling it average... Dividing 1 number by another is not the average

Comment: it's interesting why you are using a `ConcurrentHashMap` instead of a plain `Map` here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this

```
private static String asPercent(long l1, long l2) {
    return String.format("%2.2f%%", ((float) l1 / l2 * 100));
}
```

and

```
final Map<String, String> percentMap = map1.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, entry -> asPercent(entry.getValue(), map2.get(entry.getKey()))));
System.out.println(percentMap);
```

This assumes that for every key you have in `map1` there is an entry in `map2`.

My code produces `16.67%` and you wanted `16.66%`; if you really need truncation instead of a more accurate (mathematically) rounding, you will probably need to add some rounding code.